# How can I make a 10 second countdown timer before a download button link appears?

Tags: javascript, timer, download, countdown

On a download page, I would like to have it so that when the page loads, a 10 second timer automatically starts. On the page, I would like some text to say something like "You can begin your download in 10 seconds..." Then, after the time is up a download button appears for people to click on and start their download.

How can I do this, and what code do I use to include it into a page?

Comment: @Marty Wallace: MegaUpload sort of thing, I suppose.

Comment: I want to monitor and prevent hotlinking. Also, some files are going to be big so I want people to wait before they can download the files... so it doesn't impact my server.

Comment: Surely this question has been answered before.

Comment: It could have been, but I looked everywhere and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 11):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/rATW7/

It's backwards-compatible and not so secure, but 10 seconds isn't much to worry about anyways.

Comment: @Omar Anyone can inspect the source and get the download link without waiting 10 seconds.

Comment: Are you really 13 minitech? Bravo on your coding skills (+1) so young, you will go far :)

Comment: @Omar: If you really wanted it to be secure, you would have to implement server-side validation too, and that is just wasted effort for a 10-second wait IMO. Also it's not intuitive to people browsing without JavaScript. Luckily, it will actually take people over 10 seconds to modify and bypass the script, so it doesn't matter anyways.

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone for the help.. appreciate it. You all convinced me NOT to include this in my site. I thought it would be a good add... guess not LOL! :P

Comment: Well the only real issue is that without the server side validation someone could create something like a greasemonkey script that bypassed it for all downloads on your site.

So not really an issue unless you have tons of DLs.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `setInterval()` to do this.

Note that make sure the `countdownElement` has an existing text node, which can be any whitespace. If you can't guarantee that, just use `innerHTML` or `innerText/textContent`.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown'),
        downloadButton = document.getElementById('download'),
        seconds = 10,
        second = 0,
        interval;

    downloadButton.style.display = 'none';

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        countdownElement.firstChild.data = 'You can start your download in ' + (seconds - second) + ' seconds';
        if (second >= seconds) {
            downloadButton.style.display = 'block';
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        second++;
    }, 1000);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/tFw2a/).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with php so I'm unsure of what you mean by the countdown element.

Comment: @Omar The fiddle may be easier to understand. There is no PHP in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Noone could ensure that your intervals are exact, especially if tab (or browser) is inactive (see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs)), so it's better to rely on time difference instead of counter:

```
var sTime = new Date().getTime();
var countDown = 30;

function UpdateTime() {
    var cTime = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = cTime - sTime;
    var seconds = countDown - Math.floor(diff / 1000);
    //show seconds
}
UpdateTime();
var counter = setInterval(UpdateTime, 500);
```

The [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysilvestrov/bUZd8/1/)

Comment: I provided an alternate answer which is a modification your Fiddle solution which uses no JQuery and works with hours.

Answer (score 3):

A modification of the Fiddle provided by Yuriy which does NOT use JQuery, and works with hours as well if the # of seconds are large enough.

```
<div id="countdowntimertxt" class="countdowntimer">00:00:00</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sTime = new Date().getTime();
    var countDown = 3700; // Number of seconds to count down from.        

    function UpdateCountDownTime() {
        var cTime = new Date().getTime();
        var diff = cTime - sTime;
        var timeStr = '';
        var seconds = countDown - Math.floor(diff / 1000);
        if (seconds >= 0) {
            var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor( (seconds-(hours*3600)) / 60);
            seconds -= (hours*3600) + (minutes*60);
            if( hours < 10 ){
                timeStr = "0" + hours;
            }else{
                timeStr = hours;
            }
            if( minutes < 10 ){
                timeStr = timeStr + ":0" + minutes;
            }else{
                timeStr = timeStr + ":" + minutes;
            }
            if( seconds < 10){
                timeStr = timeStr + ":0" + seconds;
            }else{
                timeStr = timeStr + ":" + seconds;
            }
            document.getElementById("countdowntimertxt").innerHTML = timeStr;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("countdowntimertxt").style.display="none";
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
    }
    UpdateCountDownTime();
    var counter = setInterval(UpdateCountDownTime, 500);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was writing a reply with code, but alex's reply is better than my quick & dirty solution.

Take into account that if you want to do something like what Rapidshare and others do, you will have to generate the link at the server side and retrieve it with AJAX, otherwise the only thing whoever wants to get the download immediately needs to do is to see the source code of your page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, yes you can make it very easily. Here's the live link, where you can find the codding for making countdown timer , before download link appears : http://www.makingdifferent.com/make-countdown-timer-download-button-link-appears/

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` function of javascript :

```js
// make the button not visible
setTimeout(()=>{
  // here make button visible and clickable 
},10000)

// here 10000 -> 10 seconds timeout
```