# Minimum setInterval()/setTimeout() delay on background tabs

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, browser-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome: timeouts/interval suspended in background tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs)

Is there a minimum allowed delay for `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` when being run on a tab you're not currently looking at?

This code runs `setInterval()` with a specified delay of 100ms and writes out how long the delay actually was. It also reports when you enter/leave the tab.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onfocus = function () { document.body.innerHTML += 'entered tab<br />'; };
window.onblur = function () { document.body.innerHTML += 'left tab<br />'; };
var previous = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsed = now - previous;
    document.body.innerHTML += elapsed + '<br />';
    previous = now;
}, 100);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an excerpt of the output on Chrome 12.0.742.100 on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS:

```
101
101
101
left tab
1001
1000
1004
1003
1002
1000
entered tab
101
101
101
102
101
```

I tried different values for the delay too. Any value less than 1000 results in the same behavior of it being raised to 1000 when you're looking at a different tab. Values over 1000 behave correctly. And the same thing happens with the `setTimeout()` version of this code.

Comment: Interesting. I can confirm the same behaviour in Firefox 5 on Linux.

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/gHZSW/

Comment: This behavior is present in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE, Safari or Opera...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know your example was for Chrome, but for Firefox at least, from the [Firefox 5 Release Notes](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/5.0/releasenotes/) (under "What's New in Firefox").

> Background tabs have setTimeout and
>   setInterval clamped to 1000ms to
>   improve performance

---

Oh, and I just realised this has already been asked in regard to chrome, over here: [Chrome: timeouts/interval suspended in background tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs). There's a link there that shows that this *is* also true in Chrome.