# JavaScript setInterval Limits?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have an application using JavaScript's `setInterval()` to run a digital clock. I was wondering if it has a timeout, or limit, to the amount of times it can execute this function.

Comment: You mean how many times the callback will be executed? No, there is no limit. Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the given function will keep being executed until you clear the interval manually with `clearInterval()`

Note that in most browsers, your function will still be executed when the page is in a background tab, but mobile browsers (notably IOS5 Safari) may free the page until its focused / visible again.

Answer (score 37):

`setInterval()` will run infinitely.

If you wish to terminate the 'loop' you can use clearInterval. For example:

```
var counter = 0;

var looper = setInterval(function(){ 
    counter++;
    console.log("Counter is: " + counter);

    if (counter >= 5)
    {
        clearInterval(looper);
    }

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there is not limit to the number of times your interval will run, however if you intend to run a timer indefinitely you should consider the info here:

[Minimum setInterval()/setTimeout() delay on background tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563859/minimum-setinterval-settimeout-delay-on-background-tabs)

If your user is likely to tab-out, 1 second seems to be safe minimum interval