# Timer stops when I focus out of the window

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a timer set on my application using html 5 and jquery. Now when I move on to different tab or I minimize my window, the timer for that few seconds stops. I do not want this. And again as I open the window(tab or browser page, whatever u say)the timer starts. But it gets pause for those seconds. What should be the issue ? What code should I write for it ?

I want that even though I minimize my window or look at new tab, my timer should be on.

Code for getting the timer is:

*Here the timer is set and it runs, but as soon as i move my focus to other page, the timer is paused. A function is just shown here.*

```
function showTime()
{
    if(ms>=100){
        ms = 0;
        s++;
    }
    // calculates seconds and hours also

    var temp= $("#clock").text(checkTime(h)+":"+checkTime(m)+":"+checkTime(s)+"."+checkTime(ms));
    if(windows_focus=true){
timer=setTimeout('showTime()', 10);}
else if(windows_focus=false){
timer=setTimeout('showTime()', 100);
}
}
```

checktime is  a function which just add a zero in front of numbers<10.

I just added in windows_focus=false also, as I thought if I move away, then also it should work, but i am not getting.

I tried using setInterval also, when I use setInterval, then even though I minimize the window the timer is getting started. But the problem is that the time runs in a really weird manner. Runs very very fast.

Can anyone please help me out.

http://jsfiddle.net/JWxS6/44/ this might be useful to see my code.

I am really new, please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pausing setInterval when page/ browser is out of focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483525/pausing-setinterval-when-page-browser-is-out-of-focus)

Comment: :( any answers to this post?