# setInterval, non active tab in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, setinterval

```
cyanBlick();
var intervalID;
intervalID = setInterval(cyanBlick, 7000);

function cyanBlick() {
    $(".anim").each( function(indx, element) {
        $(element).delay(indx * 1000).fadeIn(250).delay(500).fadeOut(250);
    });
}
```

I have code for animating elements with class .anim. Interval 7sec. But when I leave page in non-active tab, and return after some time, animation don't work in non-active tab. I see chaotic fading  elements. Can you tell some solution for this problem?

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/uNmks/

link with animation

Comment: mind posting a live example on jsfiddle.net? The problem is not that the tab goes inactive. It has to do with the way you call your animation.

Answer (score 1):

Interval timers may be slowed down, delayed or stopped when a tab window is not visible in Firefox or Chrome.  One solution is to stop the animation when the window is no longer visible and restart it again when it become visible.

See my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737067/jquery-setinterval-too-fast-when-coming-from-another-tab/6737154#6737154) on this topic for other work-around ideas.

Comment: download library visibility.js, search solution

Answer (score 0):

See the second note at http://api.jquery.com/animate/#notes-0