# setinterval in Chrome not working like Mozilla

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events

I have a piece of code which works well in Mozilla but doesn't in Chrome.

```
 function yoxi(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("GET", "yoxi.php", false);
    xhr.send(null);
}

function getirus(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("GET", "getirus.php", false);
    xhr.send(null);
    document.getElementById('onlineus').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
}

setInterval(yoxi, 5000);
setInterval(getirus, 5000);
```

`setinterval` doesn't work in Chrome repeatedly.
What may be the problem?

Comment: What does not work (and what parts do work)? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Don't use synchronous XHR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    yoxi();
}, 5000);

setInterval(function() {
    getirus();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Why? What difference does it make?

Comment: @Bergi, I don't know the difference, but once i had the same problem and i found solution only by declaring function in setInterval

Comment: the problem remains.

Comment: what version of chrome do you test?

Comment: what may be the problem. it seems everythink is OK. very interesting

Comment: i google the problem now, and found solutions like i wrote, but on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951727/setinterval-not-working-properly-on-chrome) suggested to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: i tried put setTimeout instead of setInterval. but the same thing. doesnt work

Comment: @kakajan: your problem maybe have been due to a [function expression assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572) below the interval call. There is no difference for the OPs code.

Comment: @Bergi hmm, thanks for information