# setInterval wont work when chrome tab is in background

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I have an interval that starts when my component renders. this interval will get chart data from server and draw charts based on the data. but after some time if the browser tab goes in background interval wont call my API and wont update data.

what should I do to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

[This is the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6952025/9517648).

The summary is: Chrome and Firefox reduce the speed of `setInterval` when the tab is in the background to improve foreground performance. The workaround is, Use repeated `setTimeout` instead of setInterval with some type of repeated setTimeout like this:
Code:

```
function nextInterval() {
    // Your logic here
    setTimeout(function() {
        nextInterval();       // repeat
    }, xxx)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your hint, I test this method and unfortunately it was unsuccessful. but based on your hint I searched and find out that I should use web workers for api calls in background. is that right?