# Why is jQuery animation getting messed up when it is not the active tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, animation

You can see whats happening here..
http://jsfiddle.net/gregguida/36SEZ/4/

Switch tabs for about 30 seconds and then come back, the animation gets totally out of hand.

I think this has something to do with the way the browser treats `setInteval()` when the window doesn't have focus but I'm not sure if that's the case. I also don't know what to do about it. Any insight is appreciated.

**Update:** also tried using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` but I'm experiancing similar results

Thanks!

Comment: See the following for Chrome's `setInterval` suspension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had seen this issue somewhere before just couldn't find it =)

Comment: It seems to be chrome-only as in Opera it works... And... aren't you copying facebook a bit? ^_~

Comment: @MrRap Actually, I think Firefox added this feature recently too...

Comment: @Digital Plane If so, Greg Guida should not use it in a web-app/site because there would be nothing that would make a hype and it would lower his site's quality in people's eyes...

Comment: @MrRap Sorry, I meant the `setInterval` suspension.

Comment: @Digital Plane Oh :D. But my comment is still valid considering facebook's popularity...

Comment: It's just a proof of concept either way, but consider how many sites use the same spinner animation. I don't think the similarity is that big of a deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same when creating an animation for my site. The way I got around it was by removing the call to `setInterval` and setting a new timeout each time the animation is completed.

Here is your code updated to use that approach: http://jsfiddle.net/36SEZ/5/

Note that the call to `setTimeout` should be called only once after all of the animation is finished. In order to make sure that happens I've put it in the `complete` function of the last animation on the last div.

Comment: Talk about going above and beyond =) Thank you so much, this saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the second note at http://api.jquery.com/animate/#notes-0