# Does setTimeout() have issues when that window isn't focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm working on a site that uses setTimeout() to do kind of a 'slideshow' with banners on my site.  Everything works fine, I have the delay set to 10 seconds.  The problem only occurs when I switch windows/tabs and do something else.  When I come back, the function runs a ton of times I (assume) to catch up or something.  Problem is, my screen starts flickering over and over to show all banners fading in and fading out.

Any ideas on a solution?  I've noticed this in Google Chrome, I also know it happens in Firefox.  Not sure about IE.

**EDIT**

Here is the snippet I'm dealing with.  Sadly, it is part of a very large script and is connected to a very complicated HTML file.

I hope you can get an idea of what is going on here at least:

```
var lval=0;
var nval=1;
setHead = function(data) {
        lval=nval;
        var index=1;
        $.each(data, function(name,value) {
            if (Math.floor(Math.random()*index+2)==index+1) {
                nval=index;
            }
            if (index==lval) {
                $('.headmaster').find('img').fadeOut('fast');
                //$('.headmaster').css('background-color',value.backgroundcolor);
                $('.headmaster').find('a').attr('href',value.url);
                $('.headmaster').animate({backgroundColor:value.backgroundcolor},'slow',function() {
                    $('.headmaster').find('img').attr('src',value.img);     
                    $('.headmaster').find('img').fadeIn('slow');                                                                        
                });
            }
            index++;
        });
        setTimeout(function() { setHead(data); },10000);
}

arrayGet = function(arr,idx) {
    $.each(arr, function(i,v) {
        if (i==idx) {
            return v    
        }
    });
    return null
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.getJSON('json/intros.json', setHead);
});
```

I'm using jQuery for the animation and the color plugin for fading the colors.

Comment: Have you checked on firebug to see how many calls is happening to your setTimeout function? Try to check this on the normal situation and after you change your tabs/windows. See if there's any abnormality on your function call.

Comment: @AdrianoRR I've already made sure.  As soon as the tab switches back, the function is called `timegone/timeoutlength` times.

Comment: Ok, can you provide us a snippet of your code or some example using your function? It will be easier to identify your problem.

Comment: The newer browsers somehow  suspend  or slow down JavaScript execution when the page is not focused. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs

Comment: that is only for really quick intervals though. 10 second timer shouldn't get suspended in background... adding another requestto see your code.

Comment: @mattacular I've added some of the source code.

Comment: @AdrianoRR I've added some of the source code.

Comment: @FelixKling The answer to that post referenced another post, that post had an answer that I think may have just worked for me.  I used .stop(true,true) for all the animated elements and it works perfectly now (I think, I'm still testing).  Feel free to post that answer as an answer so I can possibly mark it (assuming the tests work, so far they look good).

Comment: @Dade: I think in this case it would be better to close your question as a duplicate of the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening probably because you are using an old version of jQuery. Namely the one where the dev team has started using `requestAnimationFrame` API. Fortunately, they fixed it in 1.6.3. Here is an extract from their [blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/01/jquery-1-6-3-released/):

> **No more animation “worm holes”:** We had high hopes for the browser’s `requestAnimationFrame` API when we added support into version
>   1.6. However, one of the highest-volume complaints we’ve received since then relates to the way `requestAnimationFrame` acts when a tab is
>   not visible. All the animations initiated when the tab is invisible
>   “stack” and are not executed until the tab is brought back into focus.
>   Then they all animate at warp speed! We’ve removed support for this
>   API (which has no impact on the way you call jQuery’s animation
>   features) and plan to incorporate it into a future version of jQuery.

Simply update to [1.6.4](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/12/jquery-1-6-4-released/).

Comment: Oh perfect!  I realized that I was referencing a old copy on my local file system for testing.  Perfect ;)