# setInterval and setTimeout not matching

Tags: javascript, timer, match, settimeout, setinterval

I just want to know why `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` not matching time result ?

**Syntax :**

```
setInterval(code,millisec,lang)
setTimeout(code,millisec,lang)
```

and both using millisecond..

**Why I get random `i` all the time ?**

So my test function look like...

```
var i = 0;

$("button").click(function() {

  var run = setInterval(function(){
    i++; $("code").html(i);
  },0);

  setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(run);
    i = 0;
  },2000);


});
```

Why result not showing **2000** ? or what I misunderstand something ?

If min. value for `setInterval()` is **4ms** why I don't get same result ?

**Playground :** http://jsbin.com/ezeliz/1/edit

Comment: Is your question, why the interval loop is not reaching 2000?

Comment: yes , your understand right :D @Yoshi

Comment: Well, then the answer is simple. Even if you *request* an interval length of 0 milliseconds, you're not guaranteed to get it and thus should not rely on the set value. If what you're doing is timesensible, you'll need to keep track of time differences between calls yourself.

Comment: Offcourse it doesn't! [This information](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm) could be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `setInterval(…, 0)` supposed to do? It can't repeat the function after zero time, there will always be a small delay. Actually, that delay is even standardized to a [minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9647215/1048572) of 4ms. Opera 12 for example counts (nearly) to 500 in 2s, which would match that, other browsers might have a larger delay ([they are free to choose one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964806/1048572)).