# Issue with setTimeout, when other setTimeout/setInterval calls are present on a page

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a generic Javascript code snippet which all the clients add to their website. This code snippet fetches a JS library, which has some important functions which should be called if the library is fetched in time. If the library is not fetched in time, then those functions should never be called.

To implement this, I have setup a timeout which has a callback function which takes care of it(which sets a variable depending on which those important functions will be either called or not). Now, it works perfectly in most of scenarios except when the client's website already has some timeouts/intervals with very small timer value.
Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tmckM/37/, to see the issue.

I need to find a generic way to achieve this, so that if the library is fetched in time then the timeout doesn't occur in any case.

Following is the code used in JSFiddle

```
//Though the library file is downloaded in time(which can be seen from network tab) but still the timeout fires before the library execution. I need to find a workaround for this issue

var library_timeout = 1000;
//All time values are in milliseconds
function loadLibrary() {
    var b = document.createElement('script');
    b.src = 'http://yourjavascript.com/35211527623/library.js';
    b.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b);
}

function wasteTime() {
    if (!wasteTime.counter) {
        wasteTime.counter = 1;
    }
    else {
        wasteTime.counter++;
    }
    if (wasteTime.counter == 5) {
        clearInterval(wasteTimerId);
    }
    console.warn('Start wasting time');
    var initial = Date.now();
    while (true) {
        if (Date.now() - initial > 1000) {
            break;
        }
    }
    console.warn('Stopped wasting time');
}
function startProcess() {
    window.process_started_at = Date.now();
    console.log('Started the process at timestamp:', process_started_at);

    setTimeout(function () {
        window.lib_timeout_fired_at = Date.now();
        console.log('Library timed out at timestamp:', lib_timeout_fired_at);
        console.log('So, though the library file will still download, but the functions in it won\'t be called.');
    }, library_timeout);

    loadLibrary();
}
//The following line is implemented on user's website.I can't change it.
wasteTimerId = setInterval(wasteTime, 0);//If this line is skipped then library is always executed first and then timeout occurs.

startProcess();
```

Comment: So the `wasteTime` function is only a substitution for the actual code executed on the client's website?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, its faking client's code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue here. The lib loading time can vary, the `wasteTime` js load can vary, and [so can timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964806/1048572). The browser may be quite free to first execute the loaded script or fire the timeout if both are scheduled.

The solution to this is not using a timeout at all. Just change the

```
if(window.lib_timeout_fired_at)
```

in your library script to (you have all the variables avaiable already):

```
if (lib_started_at - process_started_at > library_timeout)
```

Of course you might rename/prefix them, so the overall solution might look like

```
window.lib_timeout_firing_at = Date.now() + 1000;
…
if (Date.now() > lib_timeout_firing_at)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, there is a fallback function(which undo the changes done by startProcess to DOM) which is called when the library is not loaded within the interval. So, that is why I think setTimeout is necessary as it may be the case that library server is down and library file never comes.

Comment: Then your timeout solution is fine. I don't think you can reliably distinguish between "the lib was fetched in time but not executed yet" and "the lib has not loaded yet"; you only could raise the timeout value.