# chrome setInterval() for blurred tabs not working correctly, even for periods of 1 second or larger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

I've ran into [a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome) with chrome not being precise for `setInterval()` calls. Consider the following code (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/j6AU8/), which displays a simple timer:

```
<span id = "time_left"></span>
<script>
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 10;
    hours = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
        if (seconds >= 1) {seconds--;}
        else {
            if (seconds == 0 ) {seconds = 59;}
            if (minutes >= 1)  {minutes--;}
            else {
                if (minutes == 0) {minutes = 59;}
                if (hours >= 1)   {hours--;}
                else              {hours = 0;}
            }
        }
        min = minutes.toString();
        sec = seconds.toString()
        if (min.length == 1) {min = "0" + min;}
        if (sec.length == 1) {sec = "0" + sec;}

        document.getElementById("time_left").innerHTML = hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec;

    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Using chromium (28.0.1500.52), I've opened the same script in 2 tabs, one having the focus and one hidden. After a while, if I switch to the hidden one, the timer has lagged behind for several seconds. The same holds true if the period is larger than 1'', say 2 or 3.

According to the link provided above, chrome should only exhibit similar behavior for calls less than 1''.
Is there any (pure js, not jquery), work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This timer doesn't lag, because it checks the 'real' time using the `Date` object.

```
var endTime = new Date;
endTime.setMinutes(then.getMinutes()+10);

refresh();

function refresh(){
    var diff = Math.abs((endTime-new Date().getTime())/1000);
    document.getElementById("time_left").innerHTML = 
               zeroPad(Math.floor(diff/3600)) +
         ":" + zeroPad(Math.floor(diff/60))+
         ":" + zeroPad(Math.floor((diff%60)));

    if (new Date < endTime){
        setTimeout(refresh,1000);
    }
}

// zeroPad method:
function zeroPad(nr,base,chr){
        var  len = (String(base||10).length - String(nr).length)+1;
        return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr||'0')+nr : nr;
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/TUZyd/)

BTW: using `setTimeout` has the advantage of being able to stop the timer any time ([see also...](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/14/setinterval-is-moderately-evil.aspx)).

Here's [a page](http://testbed.nicon.nl/timeouttest/) to test the accuracy of timeouts, used in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs).