# How to delay the execution of a function in jQuery without setTimeout

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, settimeout

I have two functions running in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JuFxn/8/

```
$('.child0,.child1,.child2,.child3,.child4').hide();
fadeItIn();
setTimeout(fadeItInDoom, 500);

function fadeItIn() {
    var child;

    child = 4;
    setTimeout(fadeIn, 3000);

    function fadeIn() {
        $("#child" + child).fadeIn(175);
        --child;
        if (child >= 0) {
            // Continue fading in
            setTimeout(fadeIn, 175);
        } else {
            // Start fading out
            ++child;
            setTimeout(fadeOut, 175);
        }
    }

    function fadeOut() {
        $("#child" + child).fadeOut(175);
        ++child;
        if (child <= 4) {
            // Continue fading out
            setTimeout(fadeOut, 175);
        } else {
            // Start over again
            setTimeout(fadeIn, 3000 - 1575);
        }
    }
}

function fadeItInDoom() {
    var doom;

    doom = 4;
    setTimeout(fadeInDoom, 3000);

    function fadeInDoom() {
        $("#doom" + doom).fadeIn(175);
        --doom;
        if (doom >= 0) {
            // Continue fading in
            setTimeout(fadeInDoom, 175);
        } else {
            // Start fading out
            ++doom;
            setTimeout(fadeOutDoom, 175);
        }
    }

    function fadeOutDoom() {
        $("#doom" + doom).fadeOut(175);
        ++doom;
        if (doom <= 4) {
            // Continue fading out
            setTimeout(fadeOutDoom, 175);
        } else {
            // Start over again
            setTimeout(fadeInDoom, 3000 - 1575);
        }
    }
}
```

I want fadeItInDoom to come in 500ms after fadeItIn. This works, but the problem I am having is that when the tab becomes inactive, the timing of the second pulse animation gets off. It sort of doesnt make sense though that it would do this because when the fadeItInDoom function comes in, the setTimeout has already passed. Am I correct in that assumption? or is there something else going on with setTimeout that I'm not getting?

Comment: To answer the question from the title, *"How to delay the execution of a function in jQuery without setTimeout"*: You could use `setInterval`, though `setTimeout` is more convenient to use in such a case.

Comment: You know you can stop timeouts, right?

Comment: @Kevin B Well to tell you the truth, no. I have only been using jQuery for a week haha.

Comment: the method is clearTimeout(timerid), and it's just plain old javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout

Comment: I made it so that fadeItInDoom was in a timeout variable that I cleared as soon as the first pulse finished. The timings still havent been fixed after the tab became inactive though. I think something is going on after the function gets called, but it doesnt really make any sense considering the function never gets called again after the first time.

Comment: Timing problem has nothing to do with going to another tab; it goes off sync over time.

Comment: I looked at it for 10 mins and it didn't go of sync at all. I then opened a new tab, ran it again then opened another tab for about 10 seconds, went back and the new the one was off almost instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, timers/intervals in background tabs are executed only once per second. See: [Chrome: timeouts/interval suspended in background tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs)

To fix your issue with animations, you need to use different approach: [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame), which never tell you *when* the next tick will happen, but you can at least deduce it from inside.

Tutorials:

- http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/