# setInterval not clearing when user leaves window

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I have a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/bphillips201/details/JygKB) that I've worked up that uses several instances of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. I've found that there's an issue with `setInterval` if the user leaves the page.

You may notice that if you leave the page while this interval is running, the numbers will continue to increment forever. The interval is essentially not getting cleared. This works just fine otherwise.

Here's an example of one of the instances of `setInterval` within a `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var x = parseInt($one.text());

  handle = setInterval(function() {
    if (x > -5) {
      x--;
      $one.html(x + 'px');
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(handle);
      handle = null;
    }
  }, 200);

  $box.animate({
    boxShadow: '-5px 0 0 0 #333'
  }, 2000);

}, 7000);
```

I've tried adding both `clearInterval(handle)` and `handle = null` in my if/else statement, but I simply can't get the interval to clear if a user leaves the page. Any other ways I can approach this `setInterval`? Is this just a javascript limitation?

**Update**

Strangely enough, when I log the `x` value, the console shows it displaying the -1 through -4 numbers correctly. Does `clearInterval` not run from another window?

Comment: look at how the browsers handle off tab timers. iirc they never stop they just slow down.

Comment: @rlemon you're right - "When a tab is inactive, only at a maximum of once per second the function is called." from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs). Interesting

Comment: As a side note: requestAnimationFrame completely stops when off tab. I realize it has nothing to do with this issue, but it is good to know :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` in place of `setInterval` like this :-

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var x = parseInt($one.text());
    function callOnTimeOut(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (x > -5) {
                x--;
                $one.html(x + 'px');
                callOnTimeOut();
            }
        }, 200);
    }
    callOnTimeOut();

    $box.animate({
        boxShadow: '-5px 0 0 0 #333'
    }, 2000);

}, 7000);
```

Comment: This does the trick. Chrome still slows down the `setInterval`, so it has to catch up if I leave the screen, but it doesn't overflow anymore :-) thanks!