# Javascript loading slow down when tab changes

Tags: javascript, tabs, safari, setinterval

I have a timer in my website, which ticks every second using setInterval()

It does work well, but when I change the tab, the timer gets slower.

When the window is hidden, the timer gets slow. How can I fix this??

I am using safari 8.0.7.

Comment: You need to post your code so others can inspect which part cause a heavy CPU load. Otherwise, nobody is clarified on what's going on on your  code.

Comment: This code

"var i = 0; 
setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    console.log(i);
},1000);"

gets slower when I put this in about:blank using javascript console. It is not the problem with my website

Comment: We need either code or a link to help you...

Comment: Another related answer: [Chrome: timeouts/interval suspended in background tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs/6032591#6032591)