# Chrome only load requests changing the tab focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website with a workspace, where the user can add and edit some pictures to a space, everything is work perfectly, except that now, after the start page loading, every new request I make with javascript or mouse over (ajax, background-image, insert a img tag to HTML) dont load, it keeps PENDING in the NETWORK firebug tab, but if I change the tab (CTRL+TAB or CLICK) and returns to that tab, all the requests are done with loading perfectly.

Anyone has any ideas of what can I try to solve that?

PS.: Firefox its working normal.

Comment: it's not very clear are you using Chrome or Firefox ?

Comment: anyway try looking at this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

@wezzy I know about that limitation, but I not using any timer event related to this requests.. You think that maybe could be others timer events running that kind of lag the requests?

Comment: Updated 2015/06/17:
Found some people were facing same issue and reported to Chrome team as below link:[https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447463](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447463)
But issue is still not solved. I have exactly same issue on my PHP system and this started after some Chrome version update.
I've tried all the solution I searched but all in vain. And after my test, it's not about "cache" because when I browse my system in Chrome "Incognito Windows" (works without cache) the issue still happens.
This is really annoying and driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

After my tests, I've confirmed this issue came from Chrome side and there is nothing we can do at our codes side.
Right now the only solution is to download and install the DEV or Canary version of Chrome then the hanging issue will no longer exists.
The download links are here:

[DEV version](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?extra=devchannel)

[Canary version](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html)

Since it's impossible to ask every client to switch Chrome version to solve this issue, right now we can only hold it and wait to see if next Chrome version solves this issue...