# override setTimeout in require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, prototype, require

we are using require.js in our project and we need to override the **setTimeout** in line 705 , this is the code which we need to **ignore/omit somehow** this setTimeout at all(I mean run over it) ,the problem that if I change it in the open source code explicit when I change version the code will be lost,How should I override this setTimout from outside only for the require.js file and keep it as long as I use this lib, is it possible to do it in **elegant** way in JS globally ?

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js

This is line 705

```
        //If still waiting on loads, and the waiting load is something
        //other than a plugin resource, or there are still outstanding
        //scripts, then just try back later.
        if ((!expired || usingPathFallback) && stillLoading) {
            //Something is still waiting to load. Wait for it, but only
            //if a timeout is not already in effect.
            if ((isBrowser || isWebWorker) && !checkLoadedTimeoutId) {
                checkLoadedTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                    checkLoadedTimeoutId = 0;
                    checkLoaded();
                }, 50);
            }
        }
```

FYI ,The reason that we do it is 
[Chrome: timeouts/interval suspended in background tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs)

Comment: That rings all of my alarm bells, why do you need to do it? Changing global functions and objects is *almost never* a good idea.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - see the links which I've provided with the setTimout,when we use require.js on inactive tab(I mean after opening new window ) every service load take a second!!!

Comment: But, it's in an inactive tab, the user isn't watching, why do you care how long it takes?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - I try to make long story short :) Our logic is done in the inactive tab and when new window is opened the performance become very poor because of that, do you have idea if I can somehow remove the setTimeout in elegant way from outside ? Thanks!

Comment: And what will you do instead? That set timeout is run in semi-recursion, to check whether a module is loaded or not. If you just use a normal loop, you'll freeze the entire process until all modules are loaded...

Comment: There's a link in one of the answers in the SO page you linked to that links to some interesting code http://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer

Comment: @JaromandaX - yes I've seen this but I cant use it since it's too risky .

Comment: in that case anything you do to override `setTimeout` will be too risky

Comment: @JaromandaX - I mean the risky thing is about the webWorker...What is the need for this setTimeout  ? and which risks It can be raise ?

Comment: @JhonD you can receive unexpected behavior in another places where setTimeout used. HackTimer is OK solution. In my answer - more simple and 3% probability for unexpected behaviour if will be another call with 50 ms and function with "checkLoadedTimeoutId" variable. But you can rewrite condition - for example check only for chrome browser or add additional conditions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've stated your goal is to work around the throttling that Chrome performs on `setTimeout` for tabs that are in the background. I do not think it is a good idea to do so but if you must, then you should definitely patch RequireJS instead of messing with `setTimeout` globally. You said:

> if I change it in the open source code explicit when I change version the code will be lost

This is true only if you do not use a sensible method to perform the change. It is possible to do it sensibly. For instance, you can use Gulp to take the `require.js` file installed in `node_modules` (after you install RequireJS with `npm`) and produce a patched file in `build`. Then you use this patched file in your application. Here is the `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

// Bluebird is a good implementation of promises.
var Promise = require("bluebird");

// fs-extra produces a `fs` module with additional functions like
// `ensureDirAsync` which is used below.
var fs = require("fs-extra");

// Make it so that for each the function in fs that is asynchronous
// and takes a callback (e.g. `fs.readFile`), a new function that
// returns promise is created (e.g. `fs.readFileAsync`).
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

var to_replace =
"if ((isBrowser || isWebWorker) && !checkLoadedTimeoutId) {\n\
                    checkLoadedTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {\n\
                        checkLoadedTimeoutId = 0;\n\
                        checkLoaded();\n\
                    }, 50);";

var replace_with =
"if (isBrowser || isWebWorker) {\n\
                    checkLoaded();";


gulp.task("default", function () {
    // Use `fs.ensureDirAsync` to make sure the build directory
    // exists.
    return fs.ensureDirAsync("build").then(function () {
        return fs.readFileAsync("node_modules/requirejs/require.js")
            .then(function (data) {
                data = data.toString();

                // We use the split/join idiom to a) check that we get
                // the string to be replaced exactly once and b)
                // replace it. First split...
                var chunks = data.split(to_replace);

                // Here we check that the results of splitting the
                // chunk is what we expect.
                if (chunks.length < 2) {
                    throw new Error("did not find the pattern");
                }
                else if (chunks.length > 2) {
                    throw new Error("found the pattern more than once");
                }

                // We found exactly one instance of the text to
                // replace, go ahead. So join...
                return fs.writeFileAsync("build/require.js",
                                         chunks.join(replace_with));
            });
    });
});
```

You need to have run `npm install gulp fs-extra bluebird requirejs` before running it. At any rate, you can use Gulp, you can use Grunt, or you can use any other system you want to perform a build. The points are:

1. **You have a reproducible and automated method to patch RequireJS.** If you install a new version of RequireJS with `npm`, when you rebuild your software the patch is applied automatically, so long as the code of RequireJS does not change in a way that prevents applying the patch. See the next point for what happens if a change prevents applying the patch.
2. **This method is more robust than overriding `setTimeout` at runtime.** Suppose James Burke decides in a newer version of RequireJS to rename `checkLoaded` to `checkDone` and renames the associated variables (so that `checkLoadedTimeoutId` becomes `checkDoneTimeoutId`). The gulpfile above will raise an exception when you run it again because it won't find the text to be replaced. You'll have to update the text to be replaced and the replacement so that the patch works with the new version of RequireJS. The benefit here is that you get an early warning that things have changed and that you need to review the patch. **You won't have a surprise late in the game**, perhaps after you've already delivered a new version of your software to clients.

   The methods that override `setTimeout` at run time will just silently fail to do their job. They'll be looking for a function that contains `checkLoadedTimeoutId`, which won't exist anymore in the new version. So they will just let RequireJS behave the way it does by default. The failure will be a subtle one. (I've run RequireJS with the proposed custom versions of `setTimeout` with a project that loads upwards of 50 modules when not optimized. I saw no discernible difference between RequireJS using the stock `setTimeout` and RequireJS using a custom `setTimeout`.)
3. **This method does not slow down every use of `setTimeout`.** `setTimeout` is used by other code than RequireJS. No matter how you cut it, adding code in a custom replacement to `setTimeout` that starts looking for strings in each function passed to it will make *all* uses of `setTimeout` slower.

Comment: Elegant method! It doesn't need to edit the file and change setTimeout itself... Only one moment that you need gulp / grunt / other task manage in the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `setTimeout` and check if the function passed as callback contains a variable used in that function from require.js (`checkLoadedTimeoutId`). If yes, call function immediately, otherwise call original `setTimeout` function.

```
(function(setTimeoutCopy) {
  setTimeout = function(fn, timeout) {
    if (fn.toString().indexOf("checkLoadedTimeoutId") >= 0) {
      return fn();
    } else {
      return setTimeoutCopy.apply(null, arguments);
    }
  };
}(setTimeout));
```

Note that there are multiple issues with this code. If you pass a function to `setTimeout` which contains `checkLoadedTimeoutId`, it will be executed immediately too. Also, if require.js code is minified and variables are renamed, it won't work.

To sum up, there is no good way do this. Maybe try to find a different way to achieve what you want. Also be aware that, as Madara Uchiha said:

> Changing global functions and objects is *almost never* a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this... Try add before loading requirejs:

```
function isTimeoutIgnoredFunction(fn, time) {
    // you should configure this condition for safety, to exclude ignoring different timeOut calls! 
    return time == 50 && fn.toString().indexOf('checkLoadedTimeoutId') > -1;
}

window.setTimeoutOriginal = window.setTimeout;

window.setTimeout = function(fn, time) {
   if (isTimeoutIgnoredFunction(fn, time)) {
      return fn(); // or return true if you don't need to call this
   } else {
      return window.setTimeoutOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
   }
};
```

Should work in last Chrome, Firefox, IE if no requirejs minify provided... You need to rewrite function "isTimeoutIgnoredFunction" for browsers you support and for minified require.js file.

To see what string you can use:

```
console.log((function () {
                    checkLoadedTimeoutId = 0;
                    checkLoaded();
                }).toString());
```

But in some browsers it can just something like "Function".

If you have not many setTimeout's it can be suitable solution...

Answer (score 0):

Other way to achieve it is making a ajax request of the library and patch it before load the library, but you will need to have loaded a way to make the request (vanilla js or jquery...)

The next code is an example of loading requirejs and patch it with a regexp before load it in the DOM.

```js
$(function(){
  // here you can put the url of your own hosted requirejs or a url from a CDN
  var requirejsUrl = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js';
  
  function patch(lib){
    var toReplace = /if\s*\(\(isBrowser\s*\|\|\s*isWebWorker\)\s*\&\&\s*!checkLoadedTimeoutId\)\s*\{([^{}]|\{[^{}]*\})*\}/;
    var by = 'if (isBrowser || isWebWorker) { checkLoaded();}';
    return lib.replace(toReplace, by);
  }
  
  $.get(requirejsUrl, function(lib){
    var libpatched = patch(lib);
    
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.innerText=libpatched;
    $('body').append(script);
    
    console.log(window.require); // requirejs patched is loaded
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code in this answer loads RequireJS asynchronously, which means that any code that depends on RequireJS will have to wait for RequireJS to be present before running. Say goodbye to the simplicity of `<script src="path/to/require.js"></script><script>require.config(...)</script>` (a fairly common pattern, which I happen to use).