# Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-security-policy

I am using [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) on page load, but it is blocking because of some security reason.

I am facing this problem:

```
    Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading
    of a resource at
    http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit
    ("script-src http://test.com:8080 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'").
```

I have used the following JavaScript and meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Comment: If I was you, I would try doing it with server side code, and not javascript. JS is not pretty good with CORS and similar things. Google does have options for that..

Comment: I have added a `javascript` tag to this question, because the question has nothing to do with jQuery. It affects any JavaScript. In fact, the question would be more useful if you remove the `jQuery` tag altogether, but it’s not my place to do that.

Comment: A now [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource/52011580#52011580) is correct. One reason for *"Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource"* is if JavaScript is not enabled or blocked (e.g. by [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript)) in the browser. In that case, part of the error output might be *"Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘noscript-marker’"*.

Comment: I'm unable to comment on the other suggestion to use about:config, so I guess I'll add it here. Someone recommending going in about:config and setting security.csp.enable to false. Everyone else said this is a horrible idea. I just want to say that this is the solution I decided to use as well. Very many sites have just stopped working for me altogether in Firefox, with tons of these errors everywhere. Chrome still loads them. Without knowing more about why that it is, setting security.csp.enable to false allowed those sites to load again using Firefox, and I prefer Firefox over Chrome. If the

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You have said you can only load scripts from your own site (self). You have then tried to load a script from another site ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) and, because you've restricted this, you can't. That's the whole point of [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) (CSP).

You can change your first line to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://www.google.com">
```

Or, alternatively, it may be worth removing that line completely until you find out more about CSP. Your current CSP is pretty lax anyway (allowing `unsafe-inline`, `unsafe-eval` and a `default-src` of `*`), so it is probably not adding too much value, to be honest.

Comment: This is an unsafe workaround - [Google's CSP checker](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) gives this line multiple Severe failures.  (Unfortunately implementing a good CSP is not trivial and it needs to be customized per site.)

Comment: I take issue with this comment. The issues with the CSP are because of the original CSP. All this answer did was take that and add the www.google.com domain to this in answer to the question. Could I have suggested tightening up the CSP further while at the same time? Possibly, but I would say that is out of scope for the question. Especially as it was already apparent that the OP wasn't familiar with CSP.

Comment: Now is the CSP "unsafe"? That's arguable. Allowing unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval and a default source of * defeats much of the purpose of a CSP (hence why I also suggested removing it), but it should be remembered that CSP can *never* loosen browser controls so even this lose policy is adding some control over a page which has no CSP - as evidenced by the fact it is blocking a Google script! So "unsafe" is probably not a great term. "Too lax to be worthwhile" is maybe a better way of phrasing it. So yes this CSP leaves much to be desired but adding Google to it is not an "unsafe workaround".

Comment: Fair point that any CSP (other than "everything is fine) would generally be better than none.

Comment: There is a tiny bit of problem with that, I'm getting that error from `chrome://global/content/elements/panel.js` (Firefox) which disables debug on all the pages

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Sounds like a separate question. Could you raise one with more details and a screenshot?

Comment: I think Firefox with version 97 and onward go overboard and CSP doesn't allow loading scripts from same site either (at random). For example I couldn't add comment here because CSP was blocking all SO scripts, until I disabled CSP and then managed to leave comment. I thought it might be a random glitch so I enabled CSP again and restart firefox to exact same effect.

Comment: I'm not seeing that with Firefox version 99. Sure it's not some local extension or setting you've enabled?

Answer (score 22):

With my **[ASP.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core) Angular** project running in Visual Studio 2019, sometimes I get this error message in the Firefox console:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).

In Chrome, the error message is instead:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

In my case it had nothing to do with my Content Security Policy, but instead was simply the result of a TypeScript error on my part.

Check your IDE output window for a TypeScript error, like:

```
> ERROR in src/app/shared/models/person.model.ts(8,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bool'.
>
> i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

<sub>Note: Since this question is the first result on Google for this error message.</sub>

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar error type. First, I tried to add the meta tags in the code, but it didn't work.

I found out that on the nginx web server you may have a security setting that may block external code to run:

```
# Security directives
server_tokens off;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  https://ajax.googleapis.com  https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net; img-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://assets.zendesk.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://assets.zendesk.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com  https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://player.vimeo.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'none'";
```

Check the Content-Security-Policy. You may need to add the source reference.

Comment: Note that this is unsafe - this Content-SecurityPolicy gets a High Severity failures from [Google's CSP Evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to allow all my requisite sites with this header:

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' stackexchange.com");
```

Comment: Is this at all advisable: `default-src *`? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: its a wildcard to allow everything, its like no umbrella in the rain to no to get wet.

Answer (score 2):

add this to nginx directives

```
http {
    # ...
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "
default-src 'self' myDomain.com *.myDomain.com;
script-src 'self' myDomain.com *.myDomain.com 'unsafe-inline' tagmanager.google.com www.googletagmanager.com *.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com ssl.google-analytics.com;
style-src 'self' myDomain.com *.myDomain.com 'unsafe-inline' tagmanager.google.com fonts.googleapis.com www.googletagmanager.com *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com;
img-src 'self' myDomain.com *.myDomain.com 'unsafe-inline' ssl.gstatic.com www.gstatic.com www.google-analytics.com;
font-src 'self' myDomain.com *.myDomain.com 'unsafe-inline' fonts.gstatic.com data;
connect-src 'self' myDomain.com *.myDomain.com 'unsafe-inline' *.google-analytics.com *.analytics.google.com *.googletagmanager.com ww.google-analytics.com;
";


    # ...


}
```

but its for **development** purposes for **production** make sure remove all `'unsafe-inline'`s

Comment: Using this in nginx, it failed with:
Description: Multi-line headers are deprecated (see RFC 7230). Some clients never supports them (e.g. IE/Edge).
Additional info: https://github.com/yandex/gixy/blob/master/docs/en/plugins/addheadermultiline.md

Answer (score 1):

For people getting this error with web workers, make sure you have included a `worker-src: 'self' blob:` (or whichever domains you need) in the `Content-Security-Policy` header to allow loading the worker.

I only found this after loading my site in Chrome, which provided a much more useful error messages than this error in Firefox. Specifically:

```
Refused to create a worker from 'blob:<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' <URL> [domains]". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

and

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https://localhost:44353/86d5f05c-f27e-44b0-824f-4ddc9882d46f' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.
```

Happy debugging!

Answer (score -1):

For me it was calling the wrong url.

In my case my express server has:

```
app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
  schema: schema,
  graphiql: true
}))
```

calling **http://localhost:5000/** was giving me this error
should be **http://localhost:5000/graphql**

Answer (score -2):

You can fix via adding code in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Feature-Policy
    Header set Feature-Policy "microphone 'none'"
    # Referrer-Policy
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    # Content-Security-Policy   
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' e.g. https://ajax.googleapis.com https://ssif1.globalsign.com https://malsup.github.io https://seal.globalsign.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://chimpstatic.com https://cdn.ywxi.net https://static.hotjar.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://static.zdassets.com https://connect.facebook.net https://script.hotjar.com https://*.livechatinc.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://ajax.googleapis.com;"
    # X-XSS-Protection
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -13):

**!!ONLY FOR DEBUGGING!!**
Do this only temporarily if really necessary at all, as this makes your browser vulnerable on all sites!

You can disable them in your browser.

#### Firefox

Type `about:config` in the Firefox address bar and find `security.csp.enable` and set it to `false`.

#### Chrome

You can install the extension called `Disable Content-Security-Policy` to disable CSP.

Comment: Don't EVER do this, aside from temporary debugging.  This is a critical security feature of your browser.

Comment: This will only fix it locally, and besides, it leaves your browser a lot more vulnerable.

Comment: Is this "advice" for testing/debugging? If so, it should be mentioned in answer to avoid spreading dangerous vulnerabilities across unaware community of people. By the way, as @NeilChowdhury said, this will fix it on your system, what about the actual website visitors?

Comment: temporary solution but helpful for debugging (plus one)

Comment: @hackel I WILL do this. I WILL.

Comment: it's definitely good to know that such a config exists. this way we can debug better. BUT this is defo not a solution to the prob

Comment: Maybe the author of this solution should consider adding a warning?

Comment: There is a tiny bit of problem with "Don't Ever" bit, I'm getting that error from chrome://global/content/elements/panel.js (Firefox) which disables debug on all the pages

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed! Dumb answers above are not for my case!

Comment: same comment, this is what i need, but yes u should give warning,

Comment: Dont do this a huge security loop hole

Comment: Don´t post hacks as answer.

Comment: Added a note to the answer