# javascript extension src-script blocked

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I want to create extension that would redirect me to handler:query,
here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
…
"content_security_policy": "default-src * ;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' ;object-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"
…
```

**background.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="bttn1" onclick="search()">Search!</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but when debugging the extension, I get the error:

```
    Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a 
    resource at self (“script-src moz-extension://0ab93926-b987-451b-ad1d-
    c183360acd8a 'unsafe-eval'”). Source: onclick attribute on BUTTON element.
```

What do I do in order to fix this?
My browser is Firefox Developer Edition 58.0b6 (64-bit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource)

Comment: Have you tried setting the Same Origin header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy .  This has solved a similar problem for me before.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox applies a [default Content Security Policy to extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#Inline_JavaScript) which disallows inline JavaScript.

You can:

- Instead of `onclick="search()"` inline in your HTML, `addEventListener` from the `.js` file instead.
- Add the hash of your inline script to the extension's Content Security Policy.

For the latter approach, hash your inline script. Yours, for example, is `search()`. There's a handy online [tool for this at ReportURI](https://report-uri.com/home/hash). Insert the hash into your `manifest.json` like so:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-55C+spmnlCUR5KgSippSbxcEepdItE3dLSUgcw1if/U='; object-src 'self';",
```