# how to perform a post request using jquery in mozilla add on?

Tags: jquery, mozilla

I am making a mozilla extension, to notify me when an event happen in a specific web page, the problem is that I am doing a POST request using jquery, but it doesn't work.

here is that part of the code (I use it in content.js)

```
var xhrt = $.post( "https://api.pushed.co/1/push", function( dataToPush ) {
  alert( "success" );
},


)
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
    alert( "error2" );
    console.log(error+"")
  })
```

Comment: Please provide details concering *but it doesn't work*

Comment: @Taplar it fires an error, please read my updated code

Comment: And what information can you gather from the request in the network tab and console regarding the response code, any response data, etc?

Comment: @Taplar all I am getting is textStatus:"error" and in the network tab, there is nothing abt that request, I think that the request is blocked coz it is a cross domain request, what do you think ?

Comment: Look in the network tab before you make the ajax request, and then case the ajax request to happen.  You will see it show up in there and it should result in some code.  Since it is coming back with an error it should be some non-200 non-300 response code.

Comment: It is still the same after the request, it doesnt change

Comment: So no code shows up?  The page that you are viewing at the time that this ajax runs, is the page running on `https://api.pushed.co`?  A non-code could indicate you are hitting a CORS error by trying to hit a different domain than the page you are viewing.

Comment: I tried it manualy using the console, and it gave me a security error, "the page's setting blocked the loading of a resource at http..."

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource

Comment: Thank you so much @Taplar I found the code responsible for that, seems that they have this "<meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin" id="meta_referrer" />" in their web page, I am gonna remove it using jquery

Comment: Good deal.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah it really helped, God bless !