# NodeJS: How to code simplest HTML+CSS+img server?

Tags: html, node.js, http

i am looking to code like it is 1999.

I want to develop a SIMPLE Node server to server one page: *index.html* styled with *styles.css* and displaying *image.png*.

Google has not shown me a simple result.  If your answer is  'Check out this cool third party software/library/npm package', that is NOT what i am looking for.  I am trying to find an answer that does not require typing 'npm i -S *foo*'.

I just want to use the built in http module to serve a basic html file, but every example and answer is find uses template engines, express, or some other additional packages.  I am not looking to get better at googling packages.  I am not trying to serve a 'Hello World' string.  I am not trying to code a fileserver.  I am looking to get better at understanding the rock bottom basics.  What is the most basic method with the least dependencies?  That is what i seek to learn.

The closest i have come still requires express

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http')
var app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'))

http.createServer(app).listen(8080)
```

but results in this error

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).
```

Looking to learn, so any advice appreciated, tia~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate.  CSP is not the question; simple http server is the question.

Comment: This looks pretty basic, is that what you were thinking? [Create HTTP Web Server in Node.js: Complete Tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/node-js-create-server-get-data.html)

Comment: Alternatively, it looks like this guy has had a go at building his own basic file server here [Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046869/11700321)

Comment: @EGC:  thanks, i saw both if those in my google searching.  The first serves a 'Hello World' string, not a local html page.  If that tut continued for one more step that would be it.

The second is a file server, not an html server.