# Loading failed for the <script> with source <url> / Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at <url>

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am getting the following errors when trying to do an AJAX post to an external form.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source <url of my external form>
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at  <url of my external form>
```

My ajax post is simple.

```
$.ajax({
url : 'https://form_url',
data: data,
method: "POST",
processData: true,
dataType: 'jsonp  ',
error: function(xhr, status, thrown)
{
// codes here
},
success: function(data)
{
// codes here
}
});
```

I read somewhere that this could be because settings in CodeIgniter is wrong. Can anyone help if this is really on CodeIgniter? Pretty new to using the framework.

Thanks!

Comment: did you read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource ?

Comment: @Vickel yeah. However, I do not have the `meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` code in index

Comment: that should be the setting for the relevant view file (where the ajax call is made, like footer.php)

Comment: odd. I don't have that on the view files. alright let me try plugging in. thanks!