# My angular project failed to load showing error related content security policy

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, angular-forms, react-forms

My code was been working smoothly,but after adding react form validation ,it shows the following on browser while building the project.
[image: Browser error and Console]

```
 **Index.html file**
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Routing</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

 </html>
```

I am sure that there is no errors with my code.But,I don't know how to solve it.Is there anyone who can help me figure my issue and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

[refer to this question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource)
You might have said you can only load scripts from your own site (self). You need to change that in the `<meta http-equiv= ...>` tag

Comment: I have no such type of meta tag in my index file

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="..." >` tag in you index file.

Remove it and reload the page again.

Comment: Check if it works fine with `ng serve --prod` command.

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot GET /` - looks like you do not have a routing to `/` on server or is missed `/favicon.ico` file.
Some servers with NodeJS will not automatically serve files in the root directory. If resource is not found ('404 Not found' pages), NodeJS lauch `finalhandler`, nitty-gritty is [here](https://csplite.com/csp212/#ExpressJS). Last versions of this `finalhandler` publishes CSP `default-src 'none'` therefore it triggers CSP violation like:

`Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:xxxx/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'"`

Previous versions of `finalhandler` had CSP `default-src 'self'` so you saw just `404 Not found` unaccompanied the CSP error.
The same error occurs when [migration to Angular 8](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30802), because it uses NodeJS with latest `finalhandler`.

Check if `http://localhost/favicon.ico` file presents and you do have a routing to serve files at the web root `/`.

Comment: The file was already existing on my directory.But when  open from http://localhost/favicon.ico , it doesn't open.

Comment: You need to specify port number, for example `localhost:4200/favicon.ico` or what port nbr you use on server. If you get 404 not found - there is no route to `/`on server. I do not know what you use as server, but Express, for example, does not serve the root folder by default. For Express you need to add `app.get("/favicon.ico", (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/favicon.ico")); });`. Check do you serve a route to `/` on your server.