# Azure Static Web App (ReactTS) - CSP blocks loading resource from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-static-web-app

My react typescript app fails to load resources from API and it returns this error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://api.xxxxx.com/v1/blogs (“default-src”).
```

I am using axios and this is how my request looks like:

```js
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Security-Policy': 'default-src \'self\'',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    };
    const { data } = await this.$http.get<Item>(url, { headers });
```

I also added this line in the index.html

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

**It allows in dev mode, but I deployed using azure static web apps and that is where it fails loading the resource, I was thinking if it has to do with any azure configs?**

### Edit1

Tried all the suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource?rq=1) question but haven't solved the problem.

Comment: Did you whitelist the domain you request the resourve from in Azure? Sounds like a server config problem to me. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should come from the server.

Comment: No I haven't, that where I should look for perhaps.