# why my youtube video not displaying an image?

Tags: youtube

on this [page](https://jobcool.fr/Travailler-dans-la-nature-sans-diplome-en-devenant-fossoyeur-ou-fossoyeuse-et-en-ayant-un-emploi-bien-paye-sans-diplome-dans-un-cimetiere.html), the video at the top of the page does not display an image unlike the video located on the side bar.
When play is pressed, there is no playback problem.
But my visitors may not click on the video thinking it doesn't work.
How can I make it appear?
the original video is [here](https://youtu.be/VnWbJbtsyv4)
The javascript code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73579891/how-do-i-make-my-youtube-videos-appear-with-fast-site-loading)

Comment: As said on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73579891/7123660), please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: the minimal code is here [link](https://jobcool.fr/single.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thumbnail `sddefault` isn't loading for an unknown reason for video `VnWbJbtsyv4`. However `hqdefault` seems to be working. So use https://img.youtube.com/vi/VnWbJbtsyv4/hqdefault.jpg instead of https://img.youtube.com/vi/VnWbJbtsyv4/sddefault.jpg.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks benjamin.