# How to prevent BrowserLink from failing with Firefox?

Tags: html, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, firefox

I am developing an .NET Core 7 website with Visual Studio 2022 and using Firefox for devtools.  I have BrowserLink turned on, but it keeps failing intermittently. From the Dev Tools console:

[image]

And in the Browser Console, it shows this:

[image]

I haven't seen this behavior with either Edge or Chrome.  But I'd like to keep using Firefox for debugging.

What is the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: Hi... I searched for the error message and found a high [voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37308542) here, could you pls check it? and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57117817)

Comment: @TinyWang Nope, that didn't work.