# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-security-policy

I'm getting Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). When I try to access login part of my website on live server.

I posted whole source code [here](https://github.com/karlo292/lightweight-blog/tree/test)

I also tried adding

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">`

But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line completely `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://www.google.com">`

Comment: Tried it, but sadly it didn't work :(

Comment: I edited my answer to try to do that if it works.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I even tried adding it to app.js (backend). I'm going to try to use another host to see if it helps.

Comment: try to see this post, link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource maybe this might be helpful to you.