# Force Angular $interval in background tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

As do we know, modern browsers stops javascript timers on tab change to improve performance. 
I found 2 questions from 2011 in about this:

[Chrome: timeouts/interval suspended in background tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs)

[How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

Now, 5 years later, I'm trying to force this AngularJS function (based in setTimeout), to work with tab in background, still having no success.

```
$interval(function(){
  console.log("Test");
}, 100);
```

Is there any way to get it to work?

Comment: My immediate answer would be, why?

Comment: I can think of an usecase - to check the inactivity of user and probably log in out of the session after few mins.

Comment: @Wawy The reason is: I'm developing a delivery system and the back-end must check every 20 seconds if there is a new request from in the database to alert the restaurant with a popup audio. So, every 20 seconds the angularjs send a http request to the back-end, but I need the page to check even if the tab is in background or minimized.

Comment: @DanielCampos Have you though about using socket.io for that purpose?

Comment: @Wawy I didn't thought about this. It's a good idea. I was reading about Web Workers, is possible to do the same with libs like http://mattslocum.github.io/ng-webworker. What do you think?