# Browser rounds to 1 sec any timeout < 1sec

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

Start function then switch to another window->any timeouts which have < 1 sec rounds to 1 sec

Maybe you will give me some magic?

```
 [jsfiddle.net/c2dcu045/1/][1]
```

Edit:
https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer
Solved problem , thx to NineBerry

Comment: Can you give a runnable example in jFiddle or Stack Overflow's code snippet tool and add it to your question?

Comment: timeout and interval aren't meant to be highly accurate - and all browsers I use will decrease this accuracy to the extent you've observed (if not even more) when the page is not in focus

Comment: updated https://jsfiddle.net/c2dcu045/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) says:

> To reduce the load (and associated battery usage) from background
>   tabs, timeouts are often clamped to firing no more often than once per
>   second (1000 ms) in inactive tabs.
>
> Firefox implements this behavior since version 5 (see bug 633421, the
>   1000ms constant can be tweaked through the
>   dom.min_background_timeout_value preference). Chrome implements this
>   behavior since version 11 (crbug.com/66078).
>
> Firefox for Android uses a timeout value of 15 minutes for background
>   tabs since bug 736602 in Firefox 14, and background tabs can also be
>   unloaded entirely.

It then goes on to say that this is only disabled for tabs with audio playback active. Generally, the time you specify when calling `setTimeout`, is not guaranteed to be respected by the browser 100%.

Why would having the callback function being called with a slower frequency be a problem for your application?

Comment: `with audio playback active` - I believe with the current version of firefox, it doesn't even have to be active - but this is a temporary workaround some bug regarding audio, so don't expect to create a dummy audio context and have your intervals/timeouts behave forever :p

Comment: cause have a sound play , and user will understand is any happening by this sound ( roulet sounds )(its alltime can be another by timeout);

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs