# What is javascript's setInterval behaviour in PC sleep mode as well as in screen lock mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

- I have observed that setInterval does not work when PC is in the sleep mode
- How it behaves in screen lock mode?

  `var count=0
  setInterval(function(){
      count=count+1;
      console.log(count);
  }, 1000);`

Comment: Put it in screen lock mode and watch if it logged anything?

Comment: The behaviour should be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs

Comment: It depends on implementation. Chrome for example aggressively throttle setInterval/setTimeout when you do anything to remove focus from the tab: switch to new tab, switch to another window, click on the desktop etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- SetInterval works fine in Screen lock mode. But it will not work in sleep mode.
- While your PC is in sleep mode all running processes are copied into main memory.
- SetInterval starts counting tempCount as soon as your machine awakes

Comment: Depends on the browser. If your tab is not active timers are throttled on Chrome 100, running at most once per minute. I ran setInterval with 60 second interval and locked the screen. Came back to find that it had executed the function in roughly 30-120 second intervals.