# Angular 4 RXJS Observable .interval() Doesn't Work In Background

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a simple timer observable which is subscribed to when a timer starts in my app. It works well, but if another browser tab is selected then the timer stops until the app's tab is selected again.

```
public timer = Observable
  .interval(100)
```

Is there a way I can keep the observable running while the tab is in the background?

**Update**

I looked briefly into running this as a Web Worker, but soon started reading about difficulties of integrating Web Workers into Angular projects.

So for the time being I'm using the simple solution of getting the start time of my timer and subtracting that from the current time to get the timer run duration. This way the timer will correct itself when when the tab becomes active again.

I did want the page title to display the timer count so that it can be seen just by looking at the tab, so I'd still like to find a better solution to this problem.

Comment: .timeInterval(); is this needed ???

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6032429/6680611

Answer (score 5):

Tabs in the background of Chrome are heavily restricted in the amount of things performancewise they can do. See this blogpost of the Chrome team: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs

> Shipping in Chrome 57, budget-based timer throttling is a further
>   extension of the timer alignment mechanism, placing an additional
>   limit on background timer CPU usage. It operates as follows:
>
> - Each background tab has a time budget (in seconds) for running timers in the background.
> - A page is subjected to time budget limitations after 10 seconds in the background.
> - A timer task is allowed to run only when the time budget is non-negative.
> - After a timer has executed, its run time is subtracted from the budget.
> - The budget continuously regenerates with time (currently set to a rate of 0.01 seconds per second). Note that this budget regeneration
>     rate can be tweaked as Chrome collects more data about throttling
>     behavior.

So running a timer ever 100msec in the background will not work dramatically slowed down due to the budget restriction in cpu cycles.

Comment: sir according to above points setinterval is not working if tab is inactive?

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt seems like that , this is working

```
let j=0;
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).subscribe((v)=>{
  console.info('j: '+j++);})
```

Check here working demo : http://jsbin.com/zufebipawe/edit?html,js,console,output

also check here : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3042

Comment: Thanks for the github link. Your jsbin works better than my own app does, but it still counts 25%-ish slower than it should do. I'm using Chrome 62.0.3202.94

Comment: @RunnyYolk- I not much sure on slower execution but I think you can ask question on github, they can provide you answer on that, I also learning things about it right now

Comment: @PranayRana its not working if i stay away from screen more then 1min