# Trying to avoid intervals on inactive tab chrome with sound file in tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, howler.js

I am trying to use setinterval, so I created another script for the same web of a stackoverflow post, saying that a mp3 should keep active the web, but mine still without working, this is my code of howwlr on tampermonkey :

```
// @require https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.15/howler.core.min.js
// @require https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.15/howler.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';


function performance_trick()
{
    if(sounds.empty) return sounds.empty.play();
    sounds.empty = new Howl({
        src: ['http://adventure.land/sounds/loops/empty_loop_for_js_performance.ogg','http://adventure.land/sounds/loops/empty_loop_for_js_performance.wav'],
       volume:0.5,
        autoplay: true, loop: true,
    });
}

performance_trick();

})();
```

Someone know what I am missing?

Just checked error console, is like not working the core

```
ReferenceError: sounds is not defined
    at performance_trick (userscript.html?id=8fbfbb66-2c0a-427e-8fd7-9c1d5b47cc87:28)
    at eval (userscript.html?id=8fbfbb66-2c0a-427e-8fd7-9c1d5b47cc87:36)
    at Window.eval (userscript.html?id=8fbfbb66-2c0a-427e-8fd7-9c1d5b47cc87:38)
    at <anonymous>:2:491
    at eval (userscript.html?id=8fbfbb66-2c0a-427e-8fd7-9c1d5b47cc87:2)
    at eval (userscript.html?id=8fbfbb66-2c0a-427e-8fd7-9c1d5b47cc87:3)
    at Object.eval (userscript.html?id=8fbfbb66-2c0a-427e-8fd7-9c1d5b47cc87:39)
    at eval (userscript.html?id=8fbfbb66-2c0a-427e-8fd7-9c1d5b47cc87:41)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:2:491
```

Comment: dont work never, and should work forever, for get all performance when is innactive, is probably the require because i get sound is undefined

Comment: error is pretty much telling you what problem is. Where do you think `sounds` is defined? Nothing in code shown suggests it is

Comment: sound should be a property of the howler library right ?

Comment: No idea. Is it supposed to be according to their documentation?

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51191818

Comment: That is probably just some object variable that that particular user created for their own project. Replace each instance of `sounds.empty` with some regular variable, eg `sound`, and it should remedy the problem.

Comment: tY!, i am going to delete this

Comment: wait, now i recive this The Web Audio autoplay policy will be re-enabled in Chrome 70 (October 2018). Please check that your website is compatible with it. google chrome dont allow autoplay!!!?

Comment: See the [autoplay policy changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). It will autoplay if certain criteria are met.