# How can I make a script keep running in background from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently created my first google chrome extension. It works, but I want to make it even better.
The goal of my extension is to be able to refresh a page at a specific time. I am able to do that, but, when I go away from the extension popup, it cancels the "timer" I set.
Here you can find some code:

Popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Refresher</title>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><b>Séléctionnez l'heure à laquelle vous souhaitez rafraîchir automatiquement la page !</b></p>
    <div id="d2">
      <form>
        <input id="input-hour" type="number" placeholder=22 min=0 max=24></input> H
        <input id="input-min" type="number" placeholder=13 min=0 max=59></input> M
        <input id="input-sec" type="number" placeholder=45 min=0 max=59></input> S
      </form>
    </div><br>
    <div id="d1">
      <button id="ss_button">Programmer le refresh</button>
    </div>
    <p>En attendant une future mise à jour, vous devez garder ce popup ouvert pour qu'il fonctionne.</p>
  </body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

Popup.js:

```
console.log("popup.js loaded")

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if(document.getElementById("input-hour") != null){
    var input_h = document.getElementById("input-hour");
    input_h.value = localStorage.getItem("hour_value");
  }
 
  if(document.getElementById("input-min") != null){
    var input_m = document.getElementById("input-min");
    input_m.value = localStorage.getItem("min_value");
  }

  if(document.getElementById("input-sec") != null){
    var input_s = document.getElementById("input-sec");
    input_s.value = localStorage.getItem("sec_value");
  }

  if(document.getElementById("ss_button") != null){
    var ss_button = document.getElementById("ss_button");
    ss_button.addEventListener('click', ss_clickHandler);
  }
  
  function ss_clickHandler(e) {
    localStorage.setItem("hour_value", input_h.value);
    localStorage.setItem("min_value", input_m.value);
    localStorage.setItem("sec_value", input_s.value);
  
    refresh_hour = parseInt(input_h.value);
    refresh_min = parseInt(input_m.value);
    refresh_sec = parseInt(input_s.value);

    countdown(refresh_hour, refresh_min, refresh_sec);

    function countdown(hours, minutes, seconds){
      var now = new Date();
      var then = new Date();
      var onesecond = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0);
    
      if(now.getHours() > hours ||
          (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
          now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
          then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
      }
    
      then.setHours(hours);
      then.setMinutes(minutes);
      then.setSeconds(seconds);
      var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime() - onesecond.getTime());
      setTimeout(function() { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "reload"}); }, timeout);
    }
  }
});
```

And finally background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "reload" ) {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
          var code = 'window.location.reload(true);';
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: code});
        });
    }
});
```

Can, please, someone help me?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome: timeouts/interval suspended in background tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs)

Comment: Most of browsers stops almost all resources for inactive tabs

Answer (score 1):

Scripts in popup.html get killed after you leave the popup so you can NOT put your interval code there.

By default, background.js is persistent but make sure your manifest.json didn't override the persistent to false.

Since your background.js is now persistent, you can create a setInterval (or whatever interval type function) that sends a message to your content.js for all the tabs that you want to refresh.