# Trigger client side javascript based on datetime

Tags: javascript, scripting, client-side, prompt

I have an event_start time and I want to run a script 10 seconds after that event start but can't figure out how to trigger the script.

```
const date = Date().toString();
const currentDateParse = Date.parse(date);
const trigger = Date.parse(startTime) + 1000 * 10
```

Then this is how I'm attempting to trigger the script but it's not working. How do I start my function when the `currentDateParse` is equal to `trigger`. Or, put more simply, 10 seconds after the event starts.

```
if (currentDateParse = trigger)
   <function code underneath works already>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (explanations below):

```
let startTime = "18:00";
let currentTime = new Date();
let target = new Date().parse(startTime);

let timeout = target - currentTime + 1000 * 10; // how long should it wait till the functions is executed

function runTenSecAfterEvent() {
  // do something here
}

setTimeout(runTenSecAfterEvent, timeout);
```

### Explanations

After you calculated `target` (the start time) and `currentTime`, you need to know the time difference between them (`timeout`), so `target` minus `currentTime`. After that, you add the `10000ms`.

And then you define the function which will be executed 10 seconds after the event occurred (`runTenSecAfterEvent()`).

Finally, you create a [timeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: Thank you @natre214 - you both answered my question so I marked it correct but have a follow up... my script is sending data to my server, but after 20 minutes my page falls asleep and the script doesn't run until I refresh. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? (Or prompt it from the server).

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the time difference between now and when you want to trigger the script, and use `setTimeout()` to call it then.

```
const timediff = trigger - new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(function() {
    // do what you want
}, timediff);
```

Comment: Thank you @barmar - you both answered my question so I marked it correct but have a follow up... my script is sending data to my server, but after 20 minutes my page falls asleep and the script doesn't run until I refresh. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? (Or prompt it from the server).

Comment: Sounds related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs