# Force window to be active even when tab is not in focus

Tags: javascript, html, web, window, focus

I'm programming an incremental game using Javascript and would like the game to remain active even when the tab is minimized or not curently in focus in the browser.

I've done some research but couldn't find anything too helpful.

I did find learn about `document.hidden`, which I guess can be used to make a separate condition to run the game when the page isn't active, something like this:

```
function inactiveRunGame() {
    // do game logic
}

function handleFocusChange() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        var inactive = setInterval(inactiveRunGame, 1000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(inactive);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleFocusChange);
```

However, I'd prefer if the page always kept active and I didn't have to do this, if it's possible.

Hoping someone can shed some light on this issue.

Comment: Likely solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Web Workers might be your best bet. So you can run scripts in the background, independently from the user interface thread. I don't think WW have access to the DOM, so you have to manually handle any updates to the game's display on the main thread. Maybe by sending 'messages' from the worker, to the main thread updating the game state...

[WEB WORKERS DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).