# Start calling js function when PC wakeup from sleep mode

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

In my aspx page, I use `xmlhttp.response` to update a part of this page. This update occurs in every 3 seconds using js function.  But when my PC goes to sleep mode, this update doesn't happen. This is OK. But when PC wake up from sleep mode, I need to start update automatically without reload this page. How to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079115/can-any-desktop-browsers-detect-when-the-computer-resumes-from-sleep

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can any desktop browsers detect when the computer resumes from sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079115/can-any-desktop-browsers-detect-when-the-computer-resumes-from-sleep)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect disruptions in the JS timeline (e.g. laptop sleep, alert windows that block JS excecution, `debugger` statements that open the debugger) by comparing change in wall time to expected timer delay.  For example:

```
var SAMPLE_RATE = 3000; // 3 seconds
var lastSample = Date.now();
function sample() {
  if (Date.now() - lastSample >= SAMPLE_RATE * 2) {
    // Code here will only run if the timer is delayed by more 2X the sample rate
    // (e.g. if the laptop sleeps for more than 3-6 seconds)
  }
  lastSample = Date.now();
  setTimeout(sample, SAMPLE_RATE);
}

sample();
```