# Is it possible to Find that the client's computer is not in Sleep mood are lock mode in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am developing an eemployee management system in CodeIgniter PHP and JavaScript.

I need to find out if the client's computer is not in sleep and lock mode.

Is it possible in PHP and JavaScript or jQuery.

I am waiting for expertise Opinion and solution.

Thanks

Comment: Using javascript or JQuery, i would say no. And as PHP is server side language, of course not. Now you should find ways to detect if user is active on page using javascript, nothing more i guess.

Comment: as stated here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112708/start-calling-js-function-when-pc-wakeup-from-sleep-mode         you can detect a break in execution time

Comment: @visualex that's quite an interesting approach

Answer (score 4):

I think that you chose the wrong tools.
You should develop a desktop application for these purposes. (.NET, Java, etc.)

Server can serve as a communication point, which receives data from the desktop application.

So no, you cannot find out if computer is sleeping from a server with PHP. This can be done IF the computer sends it's state to the server through the desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Not really and every solution with an open browser window and an interval can be tricked. Best way is a native windows app/os x app.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP - **no**. PHP is server side, you cannot reach any informations about client unless client send it to you.

In JavaScript, I don't think so, and even if ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4080174/2021523)), it's on client side and can be tricked.

I suggest you to solve this problem with desktop version of your application, or at least some background proccess, which will monitor this informations.