# Force logout on Browser Close or Computer sleep on Kohana

Tags: php, authentication, kohana, logout

I wonder if it possible to force logout users session when Browser closes or Computer went sleep or hibernated?

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `ini_set( "session.cookie_lifetime", "0" );` can be used for keep session alive until browser is closed.

Comment: The session will usually be destroyed when the browser closes (cookies won't as was already said), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079115/can-any-desktop-browsers-detect-when-the-computer-resumes-from-sleep) should help for hibernate/sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not until computer goes to sleep or hibernated, this are actions that happen outside of browser knowledge. You can log users out when the browser closes by checking the user authentification based on a cookie. In [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and implicitly in Kohana this is done by setting the cookie **expire** parameter to 0. If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).