# Browser event for lid close

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom-events

This is a yak-shaving situation. My app depends on devicechange for a key feature. I found on mac computer that when you close the lid or open the lid, the camera is removed then added (I know, super weird). Is there a way to detect if the laptop lid was closed or opened? I browsed through the list of possible events on mdn and didn't see anything glaring.

Comment: How about adding a flag that flips every time you detect a change. They must start with it open, so a change must mean it's closed, another that it's open, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079115/can-any-desktop-browsers-detect-when-the-computer-resumes-from-sleep

Comment: @Chipster that's the plan, I was just looking for a way to actual detect that I need to set a flag.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks for finding that. Unfortunately I don't think that will work for my case since the `devicechange` events get fired immediately and I'd need that `setInterval` to run before the second `devicechange` event. Again thank you though.

Comment: @jensengar Ah. Okay. Got you.